# How can I use the 'FastFilterFields' property on selector fields which use alias DAC fields?

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization where I have a selector, and this selector displays two fields which are essentially the same field name, but aliased by these Alias DACs:

```
[Serializable]
[PXCacheName("Entity Mapping Alias #1")]
public class xTACEntityMappingEIN1 : xTACEntityMappingEIN  //To allow joining to the entity mapping table as alias for ID Selector
{
    public abstract new class iD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<iD> { }
    public abstract new class eIN : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<eIN> { }

    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Client EIN")]
    public override string EIN { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
[PXCacheName("Entity Mapping Alias #2")]
public class xTACEntityMappingEIN2 : xTACEntityMappingEIN  //To allow joining to the entity mapping table as alias for ID Selector
{
    public abstract new class iD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<iD> { }
    public abstract new class eIN : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<eIN> { }

    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Issuer EIN")]
    public override string EIN { get; set; }

}
```

The selector is as follows:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<xTACTaxDocument.docNbr, 
                              InnerJoin<xTACEntityMappingEIN1, 
                                  On<xTACTaxDocument.clientEINID, Equal<xTACEntityMappingEIN1.iD>>,
                              InnerJoin<xTACEntityMappingEIN2, 
                                  On<xTACTaxDocument.investmentEINID, Equal<xTACEntityMappingEIN2.iD>>>>>),
                typeof(xTACTaxDocument.docNbr),
                typeof(xTACTaxDocument.formID),
                typeof(xTACTaxDocument.year),
                typeof(xTACEntityMappingEIN1.eIN),
                typeof(xTACEntityMappingEIN2.eIN))]
```

So - the bottom two fields have the same field name.   If I want to use the 'FastFilterFields' property on the selector, how do I list those two fields, since they both have the same FieldID?

Answer (score 0):

trying to remember here but I think you would use TableName__FieldName, e.g. XTACEntityMappingEIN1__EIN, XTACEntityMappingEIN2__EIN